# launch openni_node failure: recursive print statement has occurred

Tags: ros, openni, openni-node, openni-camera

[image: Rosanswers logo]

```
setting /run_id to 02c92490-49fe-11e0-862d-001e6557f1a0
process[rosout-1]: started with pid [3010]
started core service [/rosout]
process[openni_node1-2]: started with pid [3013]
process[kinect_base_link-3]: started with pid [3014]
process[kinect_base_link1-4]: started with pid [3016]
process[kinect_base_link2-5]: started with pid [3020]
process[kinect_base_link3-6]: started with pid [3021]
[/openni_node1] Number devices connected: 1
Warning: recursive print statement has occurred.  Throwing out recursive print.
Warning: recursive print statement has occurred.  Throwing out recursive print.
Warning: recursive print statement has occurred.  Throwing out recursive print.
Warning: recursive print statement has occurred.  Throwing out recursive print.
Warning: recursive print statement has occurred.  Throwing out recursive print.
```

when trying to launch OpenNI driver in ubuntu 10.10 using DiamondBlack, I experience the error above. I've tried looking for solutions online but none of the comments was very helpful for my case. There are these ticket links that seemed to work for other people but I guess it has been removed from the site.

Any suggestion?
thank you.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/9347/launch-openni_node-failure:-recursive-print-statement-has-occurred/) by [Kinect](https://answers.ros.org/users/263/kinect/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1 on 2011-03-08

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [blueskin](https://answers.ros.org/users/26/blueskin/) on 2011-03-09**:
follow up @ http://answers.ros.org/question/269/openni_nodelaunch-warning-recursive-print

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

This is a duplicate of [this questions](http://answers.ros.org/question/269/openni_nodelaunch-warning-recursive-print)

---

Originally posted by [tfoote](https://answers.ros.org/users/3/tfoote/) with karma: 58457 on 2011-03-09

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0